# Facebook "Like Box" page disappears after brief moment in Android 4.4 KitKat WebView

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, facebook-likebox

An Android app uses a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display a [Facebook Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages). On 4.1.2 and 4.3 the page appears correctly when the following code is used.

```
String url = "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGoogle&width&height=395&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&header=false&stream=true&show_border=false";

WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_content);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

On 4.4.2 the page looks good in the full-on Chrome app; however, the behaviour is not good when loaded in the WebView as coded above. There is a brief flash of a fully-rendered page then the WebView goes totally white. Nothing is visible and scrolling does nothing.

I have used [`chrome://inspect`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) to watch the page as it loads, but it doesn't support showing network requests. The output of running `document.location.href;` at the console is `about:blank`, though, which is a clue.

Some ideas I've tried based on various threads:

- Disabling hardware acceleration

  - Using `webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`
  - Using `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Disabling JavaScript

  - This can't work because the Like Box requires JS to display at all
- Some methods on `webview.getSettings()`

  - `.setSupportZoom(true)`, `.setSupportZoom(false)`
  - `.setUseWideViewPort(true)`, `.setUseWideViewPort(false)`
  - `.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)`, `.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false)`
- Running custom CSS after the page is loaded to set a white background

  - I make sure it runs by creating an `alert()` directly afterward

At this point I may have to resort to starting an intent when running in 4.4 so the page is loaded by the browser in that case, but I would prefer to find a fix for the blank WebView. Are there any other settings I can tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above doesn't repro for me on 4.4

> I have used chrome://inspect to watch the page as it loads, but it doesn't support showing network requests.

It totally does support showing network requests. Try this - in your app comment out loading the URL, just new the WebView up. Connect via DevTools and type
window.location = 'https://....';

> The output of running document.location.href; at the console is about:blank, though, which is a clue.

Sounds like this is it. I'm not sure what the HTML/JS you end up loading does, maybe the JS tries to navigate to some weird URL? Try setting a WebViewClient that logs all `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` calls and see if you're getting a non-http(s) URL there. Try returning `true` for that URL.